# Why there isn't any nootropic tag?

Tags: discussion, tag-management, tags

Nootropics is a nice pharmacology topic. I would be nice to have that tag.

Opinions?

Answer (score 1):

An interesting topic, but the tag is only necessary if there are enough questions that would fall under it. It is a rather narrow topic (compared to health in general). If there are several questions that would benefit from this tag, please post the links here and I can create the tag. If there are no questions that would need this tag it will simply be created if such question is asked.